# Storing the 20mln records in one table or two separated tables in MySql each 10mlns ?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design

In my project, there are 20 mln users in two types 10mln for the first type and 10 mln for the second type. These users have access rights to other tables and use them. Also, I am using MySql database. My question is,  Will it affect the performance of database if I add these two types of users in one table with 20mln users. Will it be slower or 20 mln records doesn't affect the performance for DBMS ?

Comment: We don't even know what you planning on doing with your database, so I'm not sure an exact answer can be given.  If you setup the right indices for what you plan on doing, then 20 million records does not strike me as being a deal breaker per se.

Comment: I am developing attendance management system and it could include student list and their parents. Parents will access the system as authenticated user and check their children's attendance. if I have 10mln students and their parents 20mln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**20 million rows is well within the capability of MySQL.**  But you need to be considerate when forming your SQL queries as inefficient queries can lead to slow performance. 
If you are using Laravel's Eloquent then that is mostly taken care of.

Also, you might want to read [MySQL tuning](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/)

Comment: Laravel's Eloquent then that is mostly taken care of ??? 
I am developing attendance management system and it could include student list and their parents. Parents will access the system as authenticated user and check their children's attendance. if I have 10mln students and their parents 20mln. Parents will access absence table. Later Studets might be added as a user so users will be 30 mln. So joining all of them will not affect the performance or not.

Comment: @RahimjonRustamov If you use Eloquent relationships and stick to eloquent helper methods there will be lesser chances of a rogue raw SQL query slowing things down. As I said 20 mil rows is not pushing the limits of MySQL at all.  You can read up more on Eloquent in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent

Comment: @RahimjonRustamov Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a index on type then it wont matter much on number of records, though your hardware configuration is a different matter all together.

One more point to consider is, that are you doing query on both type in one statement or not. If not go for different tables , if yes it will be good to have them in one table to save a join.

Also do consider your schema as whole(which is not provided here)